# http.Handler is not called in golang

Tags: go, middleware, gorilla

I have the following middleware, first sets `currentUser` in `gorilla/context` to current user acquired from database, and the second checks if `currentUser` exists and redirects otherwise:

```
package main

import (
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/gorilla/context"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "server/helpers"
)

func withCurrentUser(db *sql.DB, next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        userId := helpers.GetCurrentUserId(db, r)

        if userId == nil {
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        }

        row := db.QueryRow("SELECT username FROM User WHERE id=?", userId)
        var username string

        switch err := row.Scan(&username); err {
        case sql.ErrNoRows:
            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
            return
        case nil:
            user := helpers.User{UserId: *userId, LoggedIn: true, Username: username}
            context.Set(r, "currentUser", user)
        default:
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func loginRequired(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        user, ok := context.Get(r, "currentUser").(helpers.User)
        log.Println(user, ok)
        if !ok {
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/login", 301)
            return
        }
        next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

Then when I register a route that requires authenticated user, I do the following:

```
router.Handle("/create_post",
        withCurrentUser(db, loginRequired(http.HandlerFunc(createPostGet))),
    ).Methods(http.MethodGet)
```

Where `createPostGet`:

```
func createPostGet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl := template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/createPost.html"))
    user := context.Get(r, "currentUser").(helpers.User)
    _ = tmpl.Execute(w, helpers.FormStruct{CurrentUser: user})
}
```

My problem is: even if user is authenticated and context is populated correctly, this route always redirects to login. I tried setting breakpoints inside `loginRequired` and adding `log.Println` (as you can see in code), and that function doesn't seem to be even called (no breakpoints stop, no log output, too).

What's happening and how to make sure `loginRequired` is called every time and checks context properly?

**UPD:** It doesn't seem to persist, I recompiled the app a few times and now it's working. Anyway, what might be the reason for such behavior (I'm positive I saved everything the first time).

**UPD 2:** I found out that the problem is connected to browser caching, but I still have no idea why it happens. When I disable browser caching, everything works and function is called every time, but while browser cache is enabled, the function isn't called at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OMG, that was stupid. I was using 301 redirect code in `loginRequired`, so redirect was permanent and browser didn't even make requests.

Comment: Ouch!  We've all been there!